# Is a return required after response.redirect()

Tags: node.js

Is it necessary to have the **return;** statement after the redirect, as in the following sample code:

```
if (!findUser(req.body.user)) {
    res.redirect("/gadda/login/?error=Unable to find user");
    return; // IS THIS NECESSARY
}

// If the above "if" statement is executed (i.e unable to find user) then there is no point in checking the password.
if (user_document.password === req.body.password) {
    res.redirect('http://' + req.headers.host + '/foo/bar');
    return; // IS THIS NECESSARY
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `return;` with `console.log('you need a return');`? Is the message logged? If yes, you need a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary but doing something like this is common.

I believe that those return statements are just there to terminate the flow of the code block after the redirect is sent.  You would typically do something like this because you have just sent a redirect (i.e. response) to the client therefore your work is done.  You want to avoid sending a second response by accident to the client (you will get an error if you do this) so ending the flow generally ensures this.  However, you are free to continue to do work after that redirect but you should be careful about how the code flows in order to avoid the double-response-send.